# Можно при переносе разделять гласные?

Tags: перенос

Можно при переносе разделять гласные? Или перенос этого слова невозможен?

> ла-ять

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [Правилах переносов](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/141-perenos) ничего не сказано о том, что нельзя разделять гласные.

> Правила русского языка позволяют расставить переносы в слове «лаять»
> 1 способом:
> ***ла – ять*** [[источник](https://slogislova.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C)]

[**проро-ем**](https://%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC.%D1%80%D1%84/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BC)
[**переше-ек**](https://perenosi.su/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BA)
[**сто-ять**](http://perenos-slov.ru/perenos/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C)